# Having trouble cleanly loading a ES6 module

Tags: javascript, es6-module-loader

I am using should() from the chai library.

It works using

```
var should = require('chai').should();
```

I'm trying to do it with ES6 modules but can only get it to work this way:

```
import chai from 'chai';
var should = chai.should();
```

Is there a cleaning one-liner way to import this module with ES6?

Comment: `import { should } from 'chai'; should();` ? No way to do that in a single statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read this article about [ES6 modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). It explains the difference between default exports and names exports.

Another suggestion is you can apply all ES6 syntax. Consider to replace `var` with `let` or `const`. It makes your variable scope more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

You could change it to this:

```
import { should } from 'chai';
```

But in your code you are also invoking the function there as well - is that a typo?

Comment: It must be invoked, since it changes the built-in types. http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should